# Flow/pattern for complex calls in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I am building a social community where a user is rewarded if someone upvotes/shares his/her answers. I also send a notification to the user when his/her answer has some interaction.

I have explained the flow though comments in the following code. 
The function post_event is exposed to the API and the flow begins from there.

```
var answerController = function(){
    Emitter.call(this);
    var self = this;
    var continueWith = null;

    var push_event = function(event, answerId, likerId, callback){

        // check for data and prepare a bacth of queries
        // has to be done like this coz mongoose doesn't (yet) support nModified, nMatched for update
        var batch = Answer.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
        batch.find(query).upsert().updateOne(update);
        batch.execute(function(err,result) {
            if(err){
                return callback(err);
            }else{
                return callback(null, result.nModified);
            }
        });
    };


    // exposed as an API call for yo/share/view
    // calls push_event
    var post_event = function(req,res, next){

            //check for data in incoming request and pass it forward

            push_event(event,answerId, likerId, function(err, num_updated_docs){
                if(err){
                    return errors.api_error({code: 500, message: err, res: res, next: next});
                }else{
                    if(num_updated_docs){
                        // create the calculateScore_args variable
                        self.emit('calculateScore',calculateScore_args);
                        res.status(200).send({message : 'success'}).end();
                    }else{
                        return errors.api_error({code: 401, message: 'event already exists for user', res: res, next: next});
                    }
                }
            });

    };


    var score = function(args){

        var asyncTasks = [];
        asyncTasks.push(function(cb){
            //update user's score
            // this is a cpu intensive function (does a small matrix multiplication)
        })

        asyncTasks.push(function(cb){
            //update answer's score  (user's score is a function of various answers)
            // another CPU intensive call, calculates confidence interval --->  score
        })

        async.parallel(asyncTasks, function(err, results){
            self.emit('notify', notifyData);
          })

    };

    function notify(args){
        // calls another controller which notifies the user(GCM) and inserts the notification into the DB
        notification.AnswerEvent(args);

    }

    self.on('calculateScore', score);
    self.on('notify',notify);

    return {
        post_event : post_event
    }
};
```

Question : I would like to know if this is a feasible pattern for a system that would receive around 100-200 req/sec. It would be great if someone can advice me on other patters (like message queue) to follow. Also, what is the best way to debug event emitter code.

Thanks

Comment: I measured my eventloop blocking time using blocked (npm) and get an average blocking time of 30-40 ms in most calls on 1 req/sec. This time does not grow linearly with increasing number of requests. But the call to update user score blocks the loop for around 300-400ms. 

User score update call is basically a function which finds the user, recalculates score (simple calc) and stores it back. Any idea why this might be happening ?

Answer (score 1):

Moving CPU intensive code out of the web server is the first and foremost way to prevent blocking.

A task queue is a very straightforward way to achieve this. With Ruby, I've used https://github.com/resque/resque with quite a bit of success in the past.

A node port such as https://github.com/taskrabbit/node-resque may be appropriate for your needs. You basically create a job, put it on a queue, and spin up some workers to chew off the required work.

Comment: I am tracking my event emitter block time and I am not sure what qualifies as a cpu intensive work (in terms of blocking the EE). what would be some good use cases to use a background job processor like resque

Comment: Anything in node.js that isn't I/O is CPU 'intensive' per say...although this is relative, and obviously the orders of magnitude are important. Things such as sorts, searches, and algorithms in general are inherently bound to the CPU. The more complex or 'expensive', the longer the 'block'. Think of trying to calculate a big prime or fibonacci for example. This would take time, while also being a synchronous block of code.